# Enable automatic horizontal scrolling when selecting text

Tags: scroll, phpstorm

This question should be really easy to answer, but I've gone through PhpStorm settings and can't find out how to do it.

When I'm selecting a portion of text in PhpStorm and it spans beyond the right-hand side of the viewport, I expect it to automatically scroll horizontally to the right. This, however, doesn't happen, which is quite annoying. It will, however, scroll left.

Can anyone tell me where to find the appropriate option in the settings in order to fix this?

**Update:** I've asked a friend to test this issue for me, and we arrived at the conclusion that it won't work only when the window is maximized. We're both using Windows 10. Another friend has tested it on a Mac OS X system and there seems to be no issue.

Comment: no settings are needed - it should just work (and works for me) - editor auto-scrolls horizontally when extending selection, using mouse or keyboard. If this doesn't work for you, can you record a screencast that shows up the issue?

Comment: I have asked some people to test this for me. I now understand the problem a bit more. It does work when the window is not maximized. It won't work when the window is maximized. As far as I know, this only happens on Windows systems (tested on Windows 10). So I think I'm looking at a PhpStorm bug here. Could you maybe test it yourself?